# Undefined reference error while building dssp

Tags: software-installation, compiling, boost

I am having following error when I try to run `make` command for dssp 3.1.4 installation in Ubuntu.

```
make all-am make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/MD_SecR_20230405/Martini3/Martini3/dssp-3.1.4' g++ -g -O2 -L/usr/lib -o mkdssp src/dssp.o src/iocif.o src/mas.o src/mkdssp.o src/primitives-3d.o src/structure.o src/utils.o -lboost_date_time -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread

/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp:361: undefined reference to boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_base::end(bool, std::nothrow_t)' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp:361: undefined reference to boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_base::~bzip2_base()'
```

There are many other undefined reference errors such as:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:355: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::finish'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:392: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::stream_end'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp:516: undefined reference to boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_footer::reset()' /usr/bin/ld: src/mkdssp.o: in function boost::iostreams::gzip_error::gzip_error(int)'
```

I appreciate any help.

I am using Boost version 1.82 and I have `zlib` and `bzip2` are installed in the system.

I expect to complete make to make dssp executable. But unfortunately, unable to do so because of the error.

Comment: What do you mean by "ubuntu20", exactly? is it Core 20, or 20.04 or 20.10? How did you install boost 1.82? Why are you using boost 1.82 when the software you are trying to build appears to only require boost > 1.54 and Ubuntu 20.x comes with at least boost 1.71?

Comment: My ubuntu version is 20.10. I used instructions in the link to install boost1.82 :https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-boost-c-on-ubuntu-20-04-or-22-04/

Comment: Should I uninstall boost 1.82? and reinstall 1.54?

Comment: I can't say for sure, since I don't have a 20.10 system on which to test - however on 20.04, I was able to build it using the default boost version installed via apt from the Ubuntu repository (specifically libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-program-options-dev
libboost-test-dev although you could also just install liboost-all-dev if disk space is not an issue)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I uninstalled boost 1.82. and started to install libboost as you suggested one by one. I am able to install, libboost-dev, -thread-dev, filesystem-dev, options-dev, but not the -date-time, -iostreams, and -test-dev. I got following error: for example, for sudo apt install libboost-iostreams-dev The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-iostreams-dev : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.71-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Any idea to overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately 20.10 was not an LTS release and is already EOL so you may have difficulty resolving that since the repositories appear to have been moved to [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Thank you. Should I use ubutu20.04 then?